# Watching jQuery click event for HTML button (not input)

Tags: html, jquery-2.0

I have been doing some searching and most of what I find relates to the html `<input type="submit">` buttons or connecting to a button by the `ID` tag. What I am trying to do is attach to every html5 `<button>` based off the `NAME` tag. 
I have tried the following but when the button is clicked it submits and I don't get any alerts before it does.

```
$("button[name=Submit]").click(function ()
{
    var error;

    alert("test1");

    if ($("#SelectedProjectCodes").val() == "") { alert("test"); }

    return false;
});
```

Also tried

```
$("input[name=Submit]").click(function ()
{
    var error;

    alert("test1");

    if ($("#SelectedProjectCodes").val() == "") { alert("test"); }

    return false;
});
```

Here is the HTML for one of the submit buttons:

```
<button formnovalidate="formnovalidate" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add Time">Add Time</button>
```

So how am I supposed to attach to all my html5 buttons?

Note: The JS in in an external file with about a dozen other functions which all work so I do know the JS file is being loaded properly and working. And all the code is in a `$(document).ready(function ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behaviour:

```
$("button[name=Submit]").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // other code
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You must put the id in the button like below

```
<button formnovalidate="formnovalidate" id="id1" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add Time">Add Time</button>
```

And also you jquery code sometime like this (call via button id)

```
$( "#id1" ).click(function() {
  var error;

alert("test1");

if ($("#SelectedProjectCodes").val() == "") { alert("test"); }

return false;});
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: As stated in my post I do not want to attach by `ID` but by `NAME`.